# Python to EXE file in one file

Tags: python, exe

So far I have used cx_freeze to convert .py file to .exe file, but I get many files. Is there a way to get it all into one executable?

I have seen that PyInstallerGUI is able to that, but it is for Python 2.7. Can it be done with Python 3.4 as well?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

PyInstaller works up to Python 3.5. Once you've installed it (type in your terminal `pip install pyinstaller`), you can do in your terminal:

`pyinstaller --onefile script.py`

where `script.py` is the name of script you want to compile into .exe

With the `--onefile` option it will create only one .exe file.

Comment: [They claim to support Python 3.7](http://www.pyinstaller.org/).

Answer (score 5):

I haven't tried it but, PyInstaller says [here](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/operating-mode.html#bundling-to-one-file) it can do that and it supports Python 2.7 and Python 3.3+.

Quoting from the linked page:

> *PyInstaller* can bundle your script and all its dependencies into a
>   single executable named myscript (`myscript.exe` in Windows).
>
> The advantage is that your users get something they understand, a
>   single executable to launch. A disadvantage is that any related files
>   such as a README must be distributed separately. Also, the single
>   executable is a little slower to start up than the one-folder bundle.
>
> Before you attempt to bundle to one file, make sure your app works
>   correctly when bundled to one folder. It is is much easier to diagnose
>   problems in one-folder mode.

Comment: Totally missed that. Thanks a lot. I would vote up but not enough reputation :/

Answer (score 3):

I found this in the PyInstaller documentation:

```
pyinstaller --onefile  your-python-file.py
```

To find more: [PyInstaller documentation](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html)