# How to convert 3 files.py to 1 file.exe?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Happy new year...

before I used to use pyinstaller to convert 1 file.py to 1 file.exe

but now I need to convert 3 files.py to 1 file.exe

because I have 3 files, 
the first one is importing from the second and the third file, the second one isn't importing anything, the third one is importing from the second file..

of course using :

```
import ....
```

thanks..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python to exe in 1 file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38024935/python-to-exe-in-1-file)

Comment: Nope, this is not my question ...

Comment: `Pyinstaller` should find the imported files, so just run it as though you were only using the main `.py` file.

Comment: I tried but I got that error: Failed to execute script .....