# how can I combine two python files into one exe file

Tags: python, exe

I am coding a calculator, how can I combine two python files into one exe file? I have 2 files, one is a program shell, question-answer, and the second file is a collection of functions in which formulas for solving examples are written.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you import the second file from the main file, you can use PyInstaller.

`main.py`

```py
import second

# ...
```

`second.py`

```py
print('Hello World!')
```

You can install PyInstaller with the command `pip install pyinstaller`. After that, run `pyinstaller --onefile main.py` to create the executable.

Answer (score 1):

If You are trying to compile python file into one exe, You should consider using pyinstaller.

```
pyinstaller --onefile script.py
```

,where script.py is the main file.
More here: [Python to EXE file in one file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38024935/python-to-exe-file-in-one-file)

Comment: I know how to create 1 file from one Python file, but I don’t know how to create 1 file from two Python files

Comment: import second pythonfile modules into the first python file then run pyinstaller on it