# Converting python script to exe. Failed to execute script

Tags: pygame, exe, converters

I have made a game using pygame and now want to convert the script to an exe file. However, when doing this and starting the exe file I get an error saying "Failed to execute script (main.py)". I have tried everything from youtube videos to reading similar questions on Stack Overflow. But nothing works, I get the same error every time. How can I solve this?

Does it have to do something with my imports?
The import that I use in my script:

- pygame
- random
- winsound
- mixer (from pygame)

Comment: can you list some of the sites you've seen and add your code?

Comment: Maybe you used `cx_freeze`, or something that makes tons of other files. You might have deleted some. In any case I think every converter checks what modules you have installed.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid all of these problems and use [`PyInstaller`](https://pypi.org/project/pyinstaller/) (link to [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38024935#38026380)):

Download this library with pip by typing in the Command Prompt:

`py -m pip install pyinstaller`

Then, type `cd [path to the file]`.

Finally, type `py -m PyInstaller --onefile [script name].py`.

---

`PyInstaller` will turn your code into one `.exe` file, in the folder `dist`, analyzing the modules you need.
After the installation, you can then delete all the other files, like the folder `build` for example.

If you need other attached files, like images, put them in the folder where the `.exe` file has been created.

---

Anyways, if you type `exit()` anywhere in your code, PyInstaller will raise an error. Simply import `sys` and type `sys.exit()` instead.